# Discord Auto Role Status

Tags: python, discord

**So I am not sure why the code isnt working. When the bot comes online that works however if I got .gg/maven in my status it doesnt give me the role**

**CODE**

```
import discord
import random
from random import choice
from discord.ext import commands, tasks

intents = discord.Intents().all()
online=False
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.',case_insensitive=True, intents=intents, status=discord.Status.online,activity=discord.Game(name="ignore", type=2))
bot.remove_command('help')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("ONLINE")
    global guild
    global adString
    global role
    guild=bot.get_guild(998691667831951442)
    adString="maven"
    role=discord.utils.get(guild.roles,id=998691667831951442)
    global online
    online=True

@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
  if online:
    if adString in str(after.activity).lower() or adString in str(before.activity).lower():
        user=guild.get_member(after.id)
        old=""
        new=""
        if before.activity is not None:
          old=str(before.activity.name).lower()
        if after.activity is not None:
          new=str(after.activity.name).lower()
        if adString in new and not(role in user.roles):
            await user.add_roles(role)  
        elif adString in old and not(adString in new) and role in user.roles:
            await user.remove_roles(role)
```